# Getting post vars with swf-upload

Tags: php, flash, post, upload, swfupload

I am using swf-upload to allow users to upload images quickly.  I need them to be able to select which galleries they want them to appear in so I have added extra controls to the form - but they are never passed in GET or POST to the upload.php catcher.

I think 'addPostParam' is what I need to set, but am not entirely sure where or how and I can't find any guide that is clear on the issue.

Also is there any problems using PHP style array names for the tags such as tag[1] tag[2] etc?

Answer (score -1):

Flash can't yet send multiple data at once in easy way. Send image in RAW data then you can give it name. Change that name to name+GET. Sample: image.jpg?property=value;